# why does jsp page get buffered? and what is the use of it?

Tags: jsp, servlets

The `JspWriter` docs says,

> If the page is not buffered, output written to this JspWriter object
>   will be written through to the PrintWriter directly.... But if the
>   page is buffered, the PrintWriter object will not be created until the
>   buffer is flushed.

Answer (score 1):

The buffering of page is done to increase the performance and reducing the network traffic.Buffering on pages depends the requirement. 
If the buffer is used then response is first written to buffer once the buffer is full the response will be flushed to client.

Setting buffer to none  can be done like this

```
<%@ page buffer="none" %>
```

So if the page is not buffered the `PrintWriter` object will directly write the response and will be rendered. But if we are using buffer like

```
<%@ page buffer="5kb" %>
```

It means buffer size is 5kb , when 5kb is full render the response.
The behavior of a page is controlled by the autoFlush attribute, which defaults to true.
For refernce - http://way2java.com/jsp/jsp-made-simple-jsp-page-directive-buffer-example/